# google analitic en local con virtual host da error en resolución de url

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Este es mi script de google analitic:

```
<script type="5c24901a010d17cd7a2e5935-text/javascript">
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-53034621-1', {'cookieDomain': 'none'});
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

lo tengo en un virtual host y al momento de abrirlo me da este error:

```
GET http://test2.me/html/www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

entiendo que no resuelve la URL correctamente como lo corrijo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el isogram ya es una versión vieja (descontinuada).

Deberías usar el script que viene ofrecido directamente en el panel administrativo de google analytics, en la sección de -Administrar/Propiedad/Información de Seguimiento/Código de seguimiento-.

Si quieres seguir usando ese script que compartes (isogram), creo que podría funcionar si le añades dos diagonales antes de las "www", para hacer que la llamada sea absoluta (no relativa).